# Using L'Hopitals Rule to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2+10)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am trying to solve the below equation
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2+10)^{1/x}$$

But am so incredibly stuck. I think I am having a mental block but I can not work out the steps to evaluate this limit. If anyone can help explain this to me I would be so appreciative. I know I get to $1/x\ln(x^2+10)$. . . well I think I know that anyway. But I am struggling with the steps and the working. I can clearly google and get an answer, but I really want to understand the steps for future problems.

Thanks.

Comment: You may try agian after reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220113/using-lhopitals-rule-to-evaluate-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-leftexx-right?rq=1).

Comment: I was just looking at that one. I just still don't understand where the e comes from?

Comment: If you don't mind using other methods, let $x = 1/u$ to get $\lim_{u \to 0} (1/u^2 + 10)^u = 10^u \left( \frac{1}{10u^2} + 1 \right)^u$. Since both these limits exist individually, the limit is $10^0 \cdot 1^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(x^2 + 10)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{\ln(x^2+10)}{x}}$. For continuous function $f$ and $g$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x))
$$

It suffices to calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+10)}{x}$. Applying L'Hoptials Rule,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+10)}{x} &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ \frac{d\ln(x^2+10)}{dx}}{{\frac{dx}{dx}}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{x^2 + 10} \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, $\lim_{x \to \infty}(x^2 + 10)^{1/x} = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+10)}{x}} = e^0 = 1$

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Now it is coming back to me, I had a mental block for 2 days over this. Thank you again